# Simple JavaScript not working?

Tags: javascript, html

Why isn't this simple JavaScript validation not working ?? The first condition run through but the second isn't going through ??

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <script type="text/javascript">     
        function process(){
            var val = document.getElementById('usrIN').value;
            var uppVer = val.toUpperCase();
            if(val == "" || val == NULL){
                alert ("Must fill in input");
            }else if (val !== uppVer){
                alert("Must be upper case");
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<form type="post" id="frmMain" />
    <p>Insert name in upper case <input type="text" maxlength="25" id="usrIN"/></p>
    <a href="#" onClick="process();"> <img src="button.jpeg"  ></a>
</form>
</body>
```

Comment: If the first condition is true, the second won't be ran (`else if`).

Comment: An input value will never be null so that is a worthless check [plus it is `null` not NULL. Also why tell the person it has to be uppercase, just make the change for them!

Answer (score 2):

In JavaScript, `null` is lowercase. Also, your use of `== ""` will also cover a `null` or `undefined` variable. Also, you probably didn't mean to do an `else if()`, you probably meant to just do a second `if` if there's no dependency on the former failing for the latter to execute.

Comment: Use `if( !val )` Its cleaner way to check for a value without checking null, undefined, and ""

Comment: also, just use `if(!val)` for the first test

Answer (score 2):

`NULL` is not defined in javascript - use `null` or `undefined`.

See here:

http://jsfiddle.net/EZqhN/